# How to check if a given ip address is reachable in C program

Tags: c, sockets, networking, ip, ping

I need a C program that will check whether a user given ip address(both ipv4 and ipv6) is reachable or not. I do not know the port no. So I cant connect and check. The functionality is more or less like ping. Except I don't want to use ping because of the overhead involved.

Comment: What overhead???

Comment: separate process created along with system call

Comment: ...but that happens any time you launch a program. There is no difference. I've answered a different question than what you've asked (I answered what I think you meant to ask), but for the way you have this worded, use ping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a raw socket, then construct and send an ICMP packet to your destination.

http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs4254/fall04/slides/raw_6.pdf

Comment: Shouldn't I know the port I am trying to connect to?

Comment: Did you read the link? Do you understand what a raw socket is?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, implementing it now

Comment: Note that what you want to do -- checking if a given ip address is "available" without having a specific service in mind -- isn't something that you can do with any degree of reliability.  It is very common for a system to offer services and yet not respond to ping or to any other connection attempts.

In other words, just because you don't get a reply to an ICMP echo request doesn't tell you anything about the availability of the remote server unless you know in advance that it *should* respond to ICMP echo requests.

Comment: Yeah ... this is a wiiiide field! ;-) Find a site with smart solutions here http://nmap.org/ - further readings are here http://nmap.org/book/toc.html

Answer (score 1):

Having an host reachable doesn't mean you will be able to get service from it. The best would be to try to connect to the correct port number. What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Besides, although ICMP is the smart way to doing it, it might not work if the host has a firewall disabling ICMP. In that case you won't get any response.

Comment: Exactly. To see if a resource is available, try to use *the resource.* Don't try to second-guess ahead of time, you're just introducing timing windows and not necessarily exercising the same paths.